# Determine the maximum IO size allowed for ReadFile/WriteFile using handle to a device?

Tags: windows, winapi, storage

How does one determine the maximum io size for `ReadFile()` and `WriteFile()` using the `Handle` created by `CreateFile()` when opening a device? Example, handle to a hard drive or handle to vss snapshot.

Comment: question is wrong asked. ReadFile / WriteFile as api accept any size, then all depend from device, which handle this request. in case storage device - this is depend from it capacity and offset read/write begin. in case filesystem - read depend from file size and write from free space size

Comment: If a device is represented through the handle, how do you find the underlying adapters max io from the handle?

Comment: @user3161924 the buffer size is internal to the device's implementation, there is no general purpose API to query the size given just a handle to the device. Different types of devices use different types of buffers of different sizes. Read the device documentation, it may or may not have specialized APIs to get/set the buffer size

Comment: As others have said, there's no IOCTL or file information class that will tell you the maximum buffer size supported by a device. You have to get it from the documentation, or trial and error. Of course there's the obvious limit of the `unsigned long` data type, and practical address-space limits in 32-bit systems.